# Reverse IP Lookup with Python

Tags: python

How can I lookup all hosts hosted on an IP Address? I have checked Bing's API, but I don't think they provide free API key anymore to make a query with an IP Address. Google probably would block after searching first 2-3 pages. I was also looking at the [shodanhq api](http://docs.shodanhq.com/python/reference.html), but I think shodan doesnt support a reverse lookup!

I am using python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: Do you want literally infinite output for wildcard DNS records?

Comment: @Wooble A server wont have infinite records..

I want something like this..

http://www.ip-adress.com/reverse_ip/, here when you enter an ip or a website address, it shows other websites residing on the same server.

Ex: 64.34.119.12 (stackoverflow) this would show the sites hosted with this particular IP.

Answer (score 2):

May be this script is for you:

```
import urllib2
import socket
import sys
import re

class reverseip(object):

            def __init__(self, server='http://www.ip-adress.com/reverse_ip/'):
                t= """ Tool made by: LeXeL lexelEZ[at]gmail[dot]com """
                print t

                try:
                    self.site = raw_input("Enter site to start scan: ")
                    self.fileout = raw_input("Enter logfile name: ")
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print "\n\nError: Aborted"
                    sys.exit(1)

                self.server = server
                self.ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5.8; Linux)"
                self.h = {"User-Agent": self.ua}

                self.write = True
                try:
                    outp = open(self.fileout, "w+")
                    outp.write(t)
                    outp.close()
                except IOError:
                    print '\n Failed to write to %s' % (self.fileout)
                    print '\n Continuing without writing'
                    self.write = False


            def url(self):
                r = urllib2.Request('%s%s' % (self.server, self.site), headers=self.h)
                f = urllib2.urlopen(r)
                self.source = f.read()
            def getip(self):
                try:
                    ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.site)
                except IOError, e:
                    print "Error: %s " %(e)
                else:      
                    print "\t\nScanning ip %s \n\n" %(ip)
            def whoami(self):
                found = re.findall("href=\"/whois/\S+\">Whois</a>]",self.source)
                for i in found:
                    i = i.replace("href=\"/whois/","")
                    i = i.replace("\">Whois</a>]","")
                    print "\t%s " % (i)
                    if self.write:
                        try:
                            outp = open(self.fileout, "a")
                            outp.write('%s\n' % (i))
                            outp.close()
                        except IOError:
                                print '\n Failed to write'
                                sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = reverseip()
    p.url()
    p.getip()
    p.whoami()
```

With tiny modifciations you can get what you want....tell me what do you think, and let me know if I can help more...Thanks!

Comment: thanks for helping.. ofcourse that is helpful and i had similar concept but with www.sameip.org ..... but i was looking for an alternate to Bing API.

Comment: always happy to help. But what more can this site add my friend??

Comment: No Actually API keeps things short and sweet ... dint want to do some extra codings :D if an API is already present! Anywaz i searched a lot, and dint find any alternate to Bing. Guess will have to go with the url you are going or sameip.org. :)

Comment: so, let me know which option you will go for and tell me how things go with you for whichever option you take :-)